# get members of any server discord. python

Tags: python, python-requests, discord.py

I am trying to get user ids from any server. This script worked before for me now it is giving two or three ids but no error. I know that discord has changed some policies to stop it. But I need it very badly. I kind of stuck with it. If there is a way to do it with requests please provide me guide for that.

```
import discord

token = ""
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.presences = True
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
global guild_id
guild_id = 905022021841338419
id_file = open("result.txt","a")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
    print(guild)

    for member in guild.members:
        a = member.id
        print(a)
        a = str(a)+"\n"
        id_file.write(a)

    
    print("Online and ready")
    id_file.close()


client.run(token,bot=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you remove the `bot` argument from you `client.run`.

Make sure you have enabled the `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` on [discord developers](https://discord.com/developers/applications) for your application.
More details about intents can be found on the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html).

Comment: I dont have access to server. I am scraping it illegally

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood your point. As far I know I'm not able to fix your issue due to the new discord policie.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you kind of need access to the server - "just saying". *sarcasm*

no but seriously, please don't do anything illegal, and if you really need to, make sure you join the server using https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=**BOTID**&permissions=0&scope=bot

Comment: Can explain it in detail

Comment: Sure. To get access to all the guild data within a server, last time I did my CompTIA SY0-601 Security+ certification, I'm pretty sure that NO service would let you access guild data from a service unless you have access to it. You have to _at least_ invite your bot to the server first, THEN you can access the data. It's simply a security risk to allow anyone to access anything they want, just with an ID. That's like letting anyone access your bank account, just with your card number. So you have to use the link I mentioned above so the bot has access to the server first.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, my answer is breaking the TOS od Discord.

First you will need to install `discord. py-self`

After that use the code below.
You do need to know that your token here must be **your** Discord token. (just create an alt and do it). Then just run the program and it should work:

````
import discord

token = ""
global guild_id
guild_id = 905022021841338419
id_file = open("result.txt","a")
class SelfBot(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
    
       guild = self.fetch_guild(guild_id)
       print(guild.name)

       for member in guild.fetch_members():
          a = member.id
          print(a)
          a = str(a)+"\n"
          id_file.write(a)

    
       print("Online and ready")
       id_file.close()


client.run(token) ```
````